# Error "This method requires a body instead of a semicolon" while trying to run method inside another method

Tags: java, methods

I have this method:

```
public void finalSuma(){
    finalSum.set(0, ((SO.get(0)+SO.get(1)+SO.get(2)+SO.get(3)+SO.get(4)+SO.get(5)+SO.get(6)+SO.get(7)+SO.get(8)+SO.get(9)+SO.get(10)+SO.get(11)+SO.get(12)+SO.get(13)+SO.get(14))));
    finalSum.set(1, (EQ.get(0)+EQ.get(1)));
    finalSum.set(2, (GR.get(0)+GR.get(1)+GR.get(2)+GR.get(3)+GR.get(4)+GR.get(5)));


    labelfinal.setText("ROF: "+(finalSum.get(0)+finalSum.get(1)+finalSum.get(2)+finalSum.get(3)));
}
```

And im trying to run it inside this other method like this:

```
public JRadioButton createIOB(final ArrayList<Double> z, final JLabel d, String title, final int x, final double y ) {
    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(title);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            z.set(x, y);
            d.setText("IOB:"+(IOB.get(0)+IOB.get(1)+IOB.get(2)+IOB.get(3)+IOB.get(4)+IOB.get(5)+IOB.get(6)+IOB.get(7)+
                    IOB.get(8)+IOB.get(9)+IOB.get(10)+IOB.get(11)+IOB.get(12)+IOB.get(13)+IOB.get(14)+IOB.get(15)+IOB.get(16))+"% ");
                }  
         finalSuma();
    });
    return button;
}
```

But the compiler throws this error "This method requires a body instead of a semicolon" when I add finalSuma() into createIOB();, this only happens when i try to run it inside this method if i run it in another part of the code it works fine, any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `finalSuma();` is outside of the `actionPerformed` method but still inside the body of the anonymous inner class.  The compiler thinks you attempted to declare a method, not call a method, so it thinks you need a method body.

It looks like you wanted to call the method, not declare it, so move it up above the ending `}` for the `actionPerformed` method.

```
    finalSuma();
} // end actionPerformed
```